# Linux keeps all cores at the (roughly) same frequency during single threaded load

Tags: linux, cpu, core

I am using TLP with powersave governor and intel_pstate driver with Intel Sidestep enabled.

I noticed that the powersave governor does its job, the cores when idle sit at 800Mhz, BUT when any kind of load is introduced ALL the cores clock up. They for all intents and purposes remain at roughly the same clock speed no matter the load. I fired up a single threaded workload, even tried limiting its core affinity to core 0 and yet they all hit their max at 1.5GHZ.

Its my understanding that it should be capable to only clock up the cores that need it to save power? Am i mistaken?

Its also worth mentioning that i am not able to set per core frequency with cpupower (It just always effects all the cores)

Should it function as i thought? If so whats wrong?

```
ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/
affected_cpus   cpuinfo_max_freq  cpuinfo_transition_latency            energy_performance_preference  scaling_available_governors  scaling_driver    scaling_max_freq  scaling_setspeed
base_frequency  cpuinfo_min_freq  energy_performance_available_preferences  related_cpus           scaling_cur_freq     scaling_governor  scaling_min_freq
```

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2300000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      =  16 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      =  30 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          =   1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct         =  62 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates       =  41

/sys/module/workqueue/parameters/power_efficient       = Y
/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0
```

```
processor   : 15
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 158
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
stepping    : 13
microcode   : 0xca
cpu MHz     : 800.069
cache size  : 16384 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 16
core id     : 7
cpu cores   : 8
apicid      : 15
initial apicid  : 15
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest ple shadow_vmcs pml ept_mode_based_exec
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs taa itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 4601.60
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```